# Set Cursor After an element

Tags: javascript, cursor, contenteditable

I have this code

```
elementSpan = document.createElement('span').className = 'mainSpan';
elementSpan.innerHTML = '<span class="childSpan">A</sapn>';
range.insertNode(elementSpan);
range.setStartAfter(elementSpan);  //the problem am having
```

Now I set the cursor to be after the `elementSpan` after inserting it into a contenteditable div but instead of the cursor to be after the `elementSpan`, it goes after the text `A` which is inside the `<span class="childSpan">` but I want it to be after the `elementSpan`. Please anyone with a clue on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Went through your question again, this is the closest I could get to work. This creates a dummy `a` with `&nbsp;` at the end and moves cursor past it. Both `a` and `&nbsp;` are important as without these some browsers (*Safari, Chrome*) force the text typed to go inside last element due to some optimisations. The code moves cursor to next element if there is one already, it can be removed by removing the `if`.

I am not an expert in range/selection APIs. Looking forward to see other interesting answers.

```js
elementSpan = document.createElement('span');
elementSpan.className = 'mainSpan';
document.getElementById('ce').appendChild(elementSpan);
elementSpan.innerHTML = '<span id="childSpan">Another text</span>'; //the problem am having
setCursorAfterElement(document.getElementById('childSpan'));

function setCursorAfterElement(ele) {
  if (!ele.nextElementSibling) {
    var dummyElement = document.createElement('a')
    dummyElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode('\u00A0'))
    ele.parentNode.appendChild(dummyElement)
  }
  var nextElement = ele.nextElementSibling
  nextElement.tabIndex=0
  nextElement.focus()
  var r = document.createRange();
  r.setStart(nextElement.childNodes[0], 1);
  r.setEnd(nextElement.childNodes[0], 1);

  var s = window.getSelection();
  s.removeAllRanges();
  s.addRange(r);
  //document.execCommand("delete", false, null);
}
```

```css
#childSpan {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ce" contenteditable="true">
</div>
```

Comment: still giving me the same result

Comment: is there a way after adding a tag then remove after curser adding text outside span.